# Understanding the BEFORE UPDATE trigger in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

In PostgreSQL, if I want to make changes on the `UPDATE` command, apparently I should trigger on `BEFORE UPDATE`. For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_update_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$$ BEGIN
    new.updated := current_timestamp;
    new.created := old.created;         --  override changes with original value
    RETURN new;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON data
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_update_fn();
```

In SQL Server there isn’t a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, and you make do with an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger. The point is that it seems to me that the trigger should work if it’s applied after the update in PostgreSQL, but it doesn’t, of course.

The question is why is the correct trigger a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, and what should I use the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BEFORE` trigger can modify the row about to be inserted into the table (`NEW`). The `AFTER` trigger runs *after* the table has been modified, so any changes to `NEW` have no effect on the persisted data.

Comment: Just to make this clear: `new` refers only to the changed rows and is the only time I can intercept changes. With `AFTER UPDATE` there is no `new` table, so the only way to make further changes would be  to do another `UPDATE`, which would, of course, result in an infinite loop. Would that be right?

Comment: There is `NEW` in an `AFTER` trigger, but modifying it will have no effect on the data stored in the table.